# Knockout - data is not retrieved from an observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I'm developing part of the web GUI which displays VM sets available during tenant creation in a cloud. The object representing this set looks like this:

```
function BoxTemplate(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(0);
    self.name = ko.observable("");
    self.description = ko.observable("");

    if (data) {
        self.id(data.Id);
        self.name(data.Name);
        self.description(data.Description);
    }
}
```

In the next step I'm trying to retrieve just IDs from the array fo the above objects. The code is as the following:

```
var boxTemplatesIds = ko.observableArray([]);

for (var i = 0; i < self.boxTemplatesList.length; i++) {
    boxTemplatesIds.push(self.boxTemplatesList()[i].id);
}

var boxTemplatesIdsAsJson = ko.toJSON(boxTemplatesIds);
```

The `boxTemplatesIdsAsJson` is then passed as an argument in the request body. However, when I print it, it's empty and null is passed to the appropriate argument in the underlaying REST API. I tried different approaches, but it was for none. Can You help me figure out what is wrong with my code? I'd be grateful. :)

Comment: `self.boxTemplatesList.length` should be `self.boxTemplatesList().length` otherwise your loop won't run as `length` returns 0.

Comment: Also, why use `observableArray` if all you need is JSON? Try this instead: `var boxTemplatesIdsAsJson = JSON.stringify(self.boxTemplatesList().map(function(x) { return x.id; }))`

Comment: Your first comment was it. I changed it and it works. Thanks! Actually, I don't need JSON. It was just a solution for the problem suggested to me by my teammate. I rather needed an array to pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If the `self.boxTemplatesList` is an observable array of the `BoxTemplate` objects, the `id` property is `ko.observable`, and you need to use round brackets to get it's value (`self.boxTemplatesList()[i].id()`):

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.boxTemplatesList.length; i++) {
    boxTemplatesIds.push(self.boxTemplatesList()[i].id());
}
```

or just using `map`:

```
var boxTemplatesIds = ko.observableArray(self.boxTemplatesList().map(
    function(item) { return item.id(); }
));
```